# Index Match -Return match based on list of possible strings

Tags: excel, list, indexing, match

I have a data set that looks something like this

```
Hostname:      Abr: Descr:
123-svr-xyz    svr  Server
456-rtr-wxy    rtr  Router
```

I would like to do a string search of the Hostname field against the list of values in the Abr field, and return the corresponding Description from the Descr field.

I understand how index match formulas work, but I can't quite figure out how to reference a list in this way.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it always deliniated with `-` between the parts?  Is it always the second part that needs to be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the part that is being found is always the second part and deliniated with "-" then you can use this formula:

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+1,FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(A2,MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+1,999),""))-1),E:E,0))
```

[image]

---

If not then you will need to use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$3,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$2:$E$3,A2)),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much. This is EXACTLY what I need. I see now where I went wrong in all of my own attempts at this.

Comment: @JohnKenny please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.